# Error in pom.xml org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.7.RELEASE failed to transfer from http://ohisnapscmnxs01:/ during a

Tags: stack

Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for net.javaguides:springboot-thymeleaf-crud-web-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.7.RELEASE failed to transfer from http://ohisnapscmnxs01:8081/repository/all-group/ during a
previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of nexus-all has elapsed or updates are
forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.7.RELEASE from/to nexus-all (http://
ohisnapscmnxs01:8081/repository/all-group/): ohisnapscmnxs01 and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
- Non-resolvable parent POM for net.javaguides:springboot-thymeleaf-crud-web-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.7.RELEASE from/to nexus-all (http://ohisnapscmnxs01:8081/repository/all-group/): ohisnapscmnxs01

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.7.2 from/to nexus-all (http://ohisnapscmnxs01:8081/repository/all-group/): Transfer failed for http://ohisnapscmnxs01:8081/repository/all-group/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.7.2/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.7.2.pom

Comment: Error due to parent pom xml